# cshtml error passing arguments

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, razor

how can i pass the arguments when i did a redirection by a button:

- when i call the method afficher it needs arguments how can i add it
- how can i pass the values of the editor-field like the arguments of afficher()

file:Index.cshtml

```
<body  onload="initialize()">


<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Afficher", "Historique"))
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Tracking Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
               <label  title= "jour " runat="server" >             day of begin                 </label>
               </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
               <input id="day_begin" name= "day_begin" />
               </div>
               <div class="editor-label">
             <label  title= " heure " runat="server" >              hour of begin                 </label>
             </div>
             <div class="editor-field">
             <input id="hour_begin" name= "hour_begin" />
             </div>
             <div class="editor-label">
             <label  title= " minute " runat="server" >              minute of begin              </label>
             </div>
             <div class="editor-field">
             <input id="minute_begin" name= "minute_begin" />
             </div>
             <div class="editor-label">
             <label  title= " jour " runat="server" >                day of end                 </label>
             </div>
             <div class="editor-field">
              <input id="day_end" name= "day_end" />
              </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
             <label  title= " heure " runat="server" >               hour of end                 </label>
             </div>
              <div class="editor-field">
               <input id="hour_end" name= "hour_end" />
               </div>
               <div class="editor-label">
             <label  title= " minute " runat="server" >              minute of end              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
               <input id="minute_end" name= "minute_end" />
               </div>





            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Done" runat="server" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Result</legend>

            <table id ="table 1" runat="server" ></table>



    </div>
    }

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Lay2.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.802584, 10.108191);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 30,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
         myOptions);
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [
         new google.maps.LatLng(36.802584, 10.108191),
         new google.maps.LatLng(36.801897, 10.102955),
         new google.maps.LatLng(36.802275, 10.110788),
         new google.maps.LatLng(36.805024, 10.109049)
         ];
        var flightmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.802584, 10.108191),
            map: map,
            title: " denden"
        });

        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        flightPath.setMap(map);
    }





</script>

</body>
```

the file HistoriqueController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Afficher(int b1,int b2, int b3, int e1, int e2, int e3)
         {
             double d1 = b1 * 10000 + b2 * 100 + b3;
             double d2 = e1 * 10000 + e2 * 100 + e3;
             ViewBag.Title = (d2 - d1).ToString();
             Parcours p = new Parcours(d1, d2);
             var model = p._segments;

             return View(model);
         }
```

i have the error :

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'b1' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Afficher(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)' in 'MvcApplication7.Controllers.HistoriqueController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Nom du paramètre : parameters
```

Comment: To pass the parameters from the form, use `<input name= "b1" />`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC Model Binder will look for values wherever it can find them, but all non-nullable parameters in the action method have to be set somehow, or you will get the exception you see.

You could add these parameters inside the form, like this (hidden or user input types):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Afficher", "Historique"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Tracking Information</legend>    
        <input id="b1" name= "b1" type="text" /> 
        <input id="b2" name= "b2" type="text" /> 
        <input id="b3" name= "b3" type="text" /> 

        <input id="e1" name= "e1" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
        <input id="e2" name= "e2" type="hidden" value="2" /> 
        <input id="e3" name= "e3" type="hidden" value="3" /> 
   <!-- etc -->
}
```

Or, if the parameters are optional, then you can make them nullable in the action method:

```
public ActionResult Afficher(int? b1, int? b2, int? b3, int? e1, int? e2, int? e3)
```